# Wine + Controller (x360ce)

Tags: linux, wine, games, steam

I've been trying to set up the Xbox 360 controller, usb connected, under wine with x360ce as shown [here](http://boilingsteam.com/a-step-by-step-guide-to-make-controllers-work-in-wine/) so I can play with it. Have been few days now and after hitting the head against the wall few times, decided to give up a bit and ask in case someone can shed some light to the matter.

So, I'm running Debian stretch 64 bits and my version of wine is 2.0-rc3. xboxdrv is installed and working fine on native linux games. There is a Steam Controller connected to the machine too and the real tone cable from Rocksmith too (this one works fine out of the box as well)

I do as follows:

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/x360ce" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
export WINEPREFIX="$HOME/x360ce"
```

After that I navigate till x360ce folder and download the latest winetricks from its [GitHub fork](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks). After that I type this:

```
bash winetricks -q dotnet45 corefonts
```

The installation goes well, then I proceed to download x360ce file, unzip it and execute it. I create the dll (xinput1_3.dll) I can then re-map the buttons and hit save, which originates a x360ce.ini file. As I can do the mappings just fine I supposed wine was then able to see my controller...

Now another 32 bits prefix is created, in which I will install steam, and The Last Remnant and Batman Arkham Asylum, 2 games reported as working with Wine + controller.

```
WINEPREFIX="$HOME/wine32" WINEARCH=win32 wine wineboot
export WINEPREFIX="$HOME/wine32"
```

Anyway, after that, I place the files into the folder of given games where the binaries to execute the game are. Launch the game and surprise! It doesn't work.

Funny enough, if I try to open x360ce again, after exporting it's prefix variable first, I get a parsing error from Microsoft .NET.

I have tried to override dll direction's in both prefixes via **winecfg** installing Directx9 independently, also tried to run the games, without steam for windows open, as a launcher from steam for linux and that didn't work either. I have also tried to install the script from Kokutoru, [here](https://github.com/KoKuToru/koku-xinput-wine), but not avail.

For more I search on the internet people don't seem to have a real problem to make this work and I'm running out of ideas.

What am I doing wrong? Any help or hints you might have?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to solve the issue, after proceeding creating the prefixes for the games as stated above, was deleteing the prefix for x360ce and using dumxinput from [kozec](https://github.com/kozec/dumbxinputemu) instead. In order to make the Steam Controller work under Wine I also installed sc-controller. To add the repository and install it I did:

```
echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/kozec/Debian_9.0/ /' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sc-controller.list
wget -nv https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:kozec/Debian_9.0/Release.key -O Release.key
apt-key add - < Release.key 
apt-get update
apt-get install sc-controller
```

To add dumbxinput I placed xinput1_3.dll and xinput9_1_0.dll next to the game executable. On Wine, using winecfg, set the respectives DLL overrides as "native" and start the game.

Don't forget to start sc-controller first starting the game to use Steam Controller under Wine.